# How to use template helper to return a modified value of a field of table

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In my mongo database i have number to defined the statut of the member, what I want to do is to get the name for this number, I did the function.
But i don't know how to use it with blaze.
In my html I have this :

```
{{#each usersList}}
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{profile.firstName}}</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{profile.lastName}}</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{emails.[0].address}}</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{profile.statut}}</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{profile.subject}}</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">{{profile.roles}}</td>
          </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And in my js i have this :

```
Template.manageMember.helpers({
       usersList : Meteor.users.find(),
       'usersList.profile.statut': function(){
            return userRightGetNameFromId(this);
       }
    });
```

I did that :

```
'usersList.profile.statut': function(){
                return userRightGetNameFromId(this);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood, what i have i to is simply that :
in my helper:

```
userRightIdToName: function(context, options) {
  if(context)
    return userRightGetNameFromId(context);
}
```

And in my html:

```
<td contenteditable="true">{{emails.[0].address}}</td>
<td contenteditable="true">{{userRightIdToName profile.statut}}</td>
<td contenteditable="true">{{profile.subject}}</td>
```

But, I have a last problem with my function, it's return undefined, what can i do ?
This code is working, i have the number:

```
if(context)
        return context;
    }
```

My function:
 userRightGetNameFromId = function(id){

```
    $.each(USER_RIGHT, function(key, item) {
         if (item.NUM == parseInt(id))
            {

                return item.NAME;
            } 
});
}
```

And my table:

```
USER_RIGHT = 
    {
        STUDENT_1:
        {
            NUM: 1,
            NAME: 'First'
        },
        STUDENT_2:
        {
            NUM: 2,
            NAME: 'Second'
        },
        TUTOR:
        {
            NUM: 3,
            NAME: 'Tutor'
        },
        RC:
        {
            NUM: 4,
            NAME: 'RC'
        },
        RM:
        {
            NUM: 5,
            NAME: 'RM'
        },
        RT:
        {
            NUM: 6,
            NAME: 'RT'
        },
        ADMIN:
        {
            NUM: 7,
            NAME: 'Admin'
        }
    };
```

Meteor doesn't wait that the function is finished ?